# Гаджеты для Windows 7 c подключением к Java приложению

Tags: windows, java

Гаджеты для Windows 7 c подключением к Java приложению. Можете ли вы помочь с кодом, который должен содержать гаджет, для подключения к серверу с Java приложением.

Comment: Тот факт, что на серере Java вообще никак не влияет на гаджет. Так или иначе, нужно работать с сокетами. Материалов по теме полно.

Answer (score 1):

Гаджеты вроде используют XML. Вывод: использовать XML для общения гаджета с java приложением на сервере...